# How do I upload simple script correctly on app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I am using gcp app engine (for the first time), I am used to only normal servers.
I have a php script that have 2 files (1-index.php 2- action.php ).
I created a app.yaml according to gcp :

```
runtime: php72 # Replace with php73 to use the PHP 7.3 runtime

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
- url: /action.php
  script: auto
```

When I deployed the app the 3 files were uploaded the 2 php and app.yaml.
I can access the index file but when i wanna access action.php it shows index content.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the handlers in the `app.yaml` matters - the first pattern match wins.

Your first pattern is the catch-all `- url: /.*` - it will match anything so that handler will get every request.

Swap your handlers' order.